# Converting SQL datetime into separate variables

Tags: php

I've been working on a blog commenting system and have been inserting the datetime with `NOW()`, and I can't quite manage to pull it back into manageable variables,

I've tried using `strtotime` like following

```
$date_time1 = strtotime( $row['chron']);
echo $date_time1;
```

also with `mktime`

```
$timeywimey = mktime ( $row['chron'] );
```

both of these are turning `2011-03-24 12:01:59` into `1300964519`

Iif possible I would be looking to split these down into `yy,mm,dd hh,mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's just **basic** string manipulations should be known to every PHP user, you shouldn't split this value but rather format it in desired format, by using either SQL `date_format()` function or PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/date) one. For the latter it would be

```
$date = date("format",strtotime($row['chron']));
```

for sake of splitting practice, you have either to use some regular expression(harder) or couple calls of [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), to split value into date ant time parts and then consequently split these into smaller parts.

Comment: Thank you kindly, Works a treat